# How do I identify the selected value from a dropdown list in the $_POST array?

Tags: php, html

I have a droplist `<select>` list in html. How do I identify the selected value in the $_POST array after the user submits the form ?

```
    <form action="subj_exec.php">

        <?php
        echo $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
        echo $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'];
        echo $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'];
        ?>
        <br>
        <select name = "subj_id">
            <?php
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $subject_id = $row['id'];
                $code = $row['code'];
                $name = $row['name'];
                echo '<option value=';
                echo $subject_id;
                echo '> ';
                echo $name;
                echo '</option>';
            }
            ?>

        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
```

The subject_id is blank in another php file

`echo $_POST['subject_id']` is blank.

Please help to identify the issue in the code.

Thanks,

Comment: should be echo $_POST['subj_id']

Answer (score 0):

The standard method for forms is `GET`, so you need to add `method="POST"` to your form.

- **get**:    Default. Appends the form-data to the URL in name/value pairs: URL?name=value&name=value
- **post**:   Sends the form-data as an HTTP post transaction

  ```
  <form action="subj_exec.php" method="POST">  //<<<< added method

  <?php
  echo $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
  echo $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'];
  echo $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'];
  ?>
  <br>
  <select name = "subj_id">
      <?php
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          $subject_id = $row['id'];
          $code = $row['code'];
          $name = $row['name'];
          ?>
          <option value="<?= $subject_id; ?>"><?= $name; ?></option>
          <?php
      }
      ?>

  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
  ```

In your file subj_exec.php, you can output the selected value with

```
echo $_POST['subj_id'];
```

Comment: i've tried this solution but it didn't work! try it yourself!

Comment: okay, i hope that it's working! i'm just telling what i got when i tried this solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Here you go :**

***index.php***

```
<form action="subj_exec.php" method="POST">

<?php
    echo $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
    echo $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'];
    echo $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'];
?>

<select name="subj_id">
    <?php
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $subject_id = $row['id'];
            $code = $row['code'];
            $name = $row['name'];
            echo '<option value="'.$subject_id.'">'.$name.'</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
```

***subj_exec.php***

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(strlen($_POST['subj_id']) >= 1) {
        $option = htmlentities($_POST['subj_id'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");     
        // Do Something here with $option
        echo $option;
    }else {
        echo 'nothing selected.';
    }
}

?>
```